# How to use Typescript Optional Chaining feature with Early Exit construct to rule out nulls along the way

Tags: typescript

Having this snippet

```
interface Bar{
    a: A|null
}
interface A {
    text: string
}

function foo(bar: Bar) {
    if(bar.a?.text === null) {
        return;
    }

    console.log(bar.a.text);
}
```

Why does Typescript complains about `bar.a` being possibly null on the line with `console.log`

> Object is possibly 'null'.

when I've already checked for it being `null` above and ruled it out through early exit?

If `bar.a?.text` is not `null` it means `a` is not `null` it the function's context.

With this example it looks like a not big deal but what about using optional chaining to rule out all `nulls` along the way in `a?.b?.c?.d?.text`.

[TS Playground (v4.2)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJygbwFDL8uALmQEEAfEAVwBtrsBfbUSWRFE5HfZSADzGIBnMFFABzBtmwxKIBGGAB7EMhiLFACgBGGYuigBKTrnzAY2jADo4Afkt8wyALwvkVWka7d8UCGEpQIADcJniMocgIyoKK1BCW1IpiFlDW9hD8BiGMMnIKysg6UCl6GJ4RZinWzq7u1OXePn4BwRHh3FEgMXEJSVVw6ZnZQA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error should really read "Object is possibly 'undefined'." While **bar.a.text** has to be *string* and **bar.a** could be *typeof A* or *null*, **bar.a?.text** could be *undefined* if **bar.a** is *null*.  Just change your check to a "nullish" one by using the equality operator (==) instead of the strict equality operator (===).

```
function foo(bar: Bar) {
    if(bar.a?.text == null) { // nullish check isntead of strict null check.
        return;
    }
    console.log(bar.a.text);
}
```

Yes it seems a little silly that **bar.a?.text** could ever return *undefined*, since none of those values should ever be *undefined* in strict mode, but that is how the operator works - when a nullish value is encountered *undefined* is returned.  If you test it out with **console.log(bar.a?.text)**, you'll see that even if **bar.a** is *null* the result returned will be *undefined*.  This is consistent with the behavior described for the operator in MDN's [Optional Chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) chapter.

If you want to keep the strict equality check, don't use the optional chaining operator, and just check if **bar.a** is *null*.

```
   if(bar.a === null) {
       return;
   }
   console.log(bar.a.text); // all good since text can never be null.
```